# How to supinate the arm

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature

How do you rotate the hand from a neutral position:

[image: arm in neutral position]

to a supinated (palm facing up) position

[image: arm in supinated position[2]]

I rotated the forearm bone on the y axis for demonstrative purposes
which twists the elbow like a balloon animal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In actual anatomy, the humerus (upper arm) would naturally rotate about 60-90 degrees, and the remaining 90-120 degrees would be performed at the distal end of the radius/ulna (essentially the wrist). To model this in a blender armature, I would rotate the upper arm bone ~70 degrees, and the forearm bone ~110 degrees.

Of course, this may introduce problems with skinning. You may want to break your upper and lower arms into 2 or 3 sub-bones each, with constraints that keep them from doing anything other than an axial rotation with respect to each other. Then you can weight paint the surrounding mesh in a gradual fashion so the mesh smoothly rotates just like in reality.

Comment: Thank you Mike! When you mentioned constraints in regard to axial rotation I understood.

Answer (score 0):

Directions I used based on Mike Metcalf's answer:

Lock editing for all axial rotations except Y axis
[image]

Rotate forearm 110 degrees

[image]

Rotate upper arm 70 degrees

[image]

for desired result:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure there is a need to post this as an answer as it seems to be just confirming that the other answer works.